# How to create cloudformation cloudwatch alarm for lambda/dynamo?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

lambda calls dynamo , want to set up a alarm which can capture latency issues in lambda while calling dynamo, I have one sample i created below for errors in lambda,
can i add latency to the following, if so how?

```
  MyAlarm:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Properties:
      AlarmName: "superalarm"
      AlarmDescription: "Alarm if lambda errors out "
      Namespace: "AWS/Lambda"
      MetricName: "Errors"
      Dimensions:
      - Name: "FunctionName"
        Value: "mylambda"
      Statistic: "Sum"
      ComparisonOperator: "GreaterThanThreshold"
      Threshold: 0
      EvaluationPeriods: 5
      Period: 60
      TreatMissingData: "breaching"
```

Comment: @Marcin - still little unclear.

Comment: What exactly is unclear? You haven't provided any details.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a second alarm, or use [metric math](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html) to create a composite metric from the latency and `Errors`.

In CloudFormation you can use [Expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudwatch-alarm-metricdataquery.html#cfn-cloudwatch-alarm-metricdataquery-expression) to define the math expression that you want.